# Sending and receiving data between two pages

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, websocket, local-storage

I'm working on a basic voting system where I have 2 HTML pages (both on the same domain).
On page 1 there are two buttons of which the person should choose one.
One page 2 I want to visualise the chosen option in a graph.
The goal is that if a button is clicked on page 1, the data on page 2 updates automatically without refreshing the whole page.

In order to do this, I tried saving the clicked option in a localStorage. I managed to get the data by writing a variable using `localStorage.getItem('')`. However, when I get the data, I have to manually refresh page 2 for the result to show. Is there a way to update the data on page 2? So if I press multiple buttons, multiple responses will show on page 2?

I also saw that there is a possibility of using WebSockets. Since I'm only familiar with HTML and JavaScript, I was wondering whether it's possible to solve my issue without setting up a server and run things locally. If that's not possible, what would be the best (and maybe easiest) way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have page 2 successfully reading a variable that you get from local storage (which is being updated by actions taken on page 1), you can make a timer with `setInterval` to read from local storage every `x` milliseconds. Then the graph will update on its own.

See [documentation for setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best and simple solution is setting specific url parameters for each button selection.

Then on the page 2 you simply show conditionally according the url parameter.